# How To Populate One Column Based On Another Columns Data In Same Table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two sets of data I joined into a single table. One was USA addresses and the other was Canadian addresses. I need the option to be able to sort by Country. So I inserted a blank country column into my table and my table now looks like this:

```
 state | country | zip
-----------------------
       |         | 
       |         |
```

I have the state and zip data but my country column is empty. Since US zip code format is 5 digits (ex. 12345)  and CAN zip are formatted like (ex. G5Y 5S7) is it possible with mysql to populate the country data with some sort of...

```
UPDATE table 
SET country = US 
WHERE zip (LIKE or =) (US zip format);
```

And then go back and use some sort of `WHERE zip LIKE NULL` to populate the rest of country data with CAN?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the length of the value in the `zip` column.

```
UPDATE table 
   set country = 'US'
 where char_length(zip) = 5;
```

then:

```
UPDATE table 
   set country = 'CAN'
 where country is null
```

-- or, in one go --

```
UPDATE table t
   set country = 
  (case when char_length(t.zip) = 5
   then 'US'
  else 'CAN'
  end);
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, that was exactly what I was looking for. It worked perfectly!!!  One day my ability to execute will catch up with my theory. lol